# IntelliJ: How do I refactor without strings/comments/etc.?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, refactoring

It's very irritating that IntelliJ seems to force me to refactor everything in the project. For example, if a there's a function called `swap` and I want to refactor it to `swapBook`, all places in the project which were once `swap`, including strings, comments, and unrelated functions, will all become `swapBook`...

How can I only refactor what's needed, like Eclipse does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you renaming method name, or are you changing method signature?

If you are using default Intellij Keymap,

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>: (Rename) Changes method names AND occurrences

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> : (Change method signature) only changes method names and method usage references, not strings/ comments